# Get All procedure / Function use in all Task

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to list all procedure / function use in all task in snowflake.
It is for a impact study, i want to move a good part of standart proc/function in a specific schema, so task will need to be modify.

Thanks

i try
`show tasks in account;`

The column DEFINITION contains all procedure/function use but it is not explotable.

Comment: You could try the OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES view but I'm not sure this works for tasks. You'll probably need to to parse this information yourself from the DEFINITION

Comment: thank you @NickW, i hopped to not parse code, but if it is the only way...